# Is it true that relatives or friends visit our home if crow make sound [caw]

Tags: belief

Is it true that relatives or friends visit our home if crow make sound [caw]

I observed this many times and It happened.

Is there any scriptural reference are there for this ?

Comment: "I observed this many times and It happened". If you know it is true why did you ask, Is it true? Do you want scriptural reference? I think Agni purana mentions it.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks ,  when you said `Agni purana mentions it.` , i dont need any reference.... You can post your comment as answer.....

Comment: You can mention that in question. I thought your were asking whether the belief was true or not?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Updated the question.....